# Window Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, troubleshooting

I have PCs `X1`,`X2`,`X3` in a `network X` (Ethernet Lan) all of them in `workgroup XW` and running windows XP pro 32 bits version.

The same PC `X1` is also in `network Z` (wifi Lan) with another PC `Z1` via a wireless router.

I want to remote desktop the PC `X1` from my external laptop `Y1`(in `workgroup YW` , windows 7 home premium 32 bits) via wirelss wifi network `Z`.

I have successfully connected my laptop `Y1` to `network Z`.

I made sure that the firewalls on both sides (both PC`X1` and `Y1`) are turned off. And set `allowed remote connections` at mycomputer > properties > properties page.

After that i enter the name of the PC `X1` in remote desktop connection program of `Y1` and tried to establish the connection. But i am getting this message everytime  i try.

[image]

FYI: i can ping the PC`X1` from my laptop `Y1`. I am the administrator so i don't need to set up account in `mycomputer> properties> remote desktop` .

Any Idea what is causing the problem?

**EDIT**

Don't know if it is gonna be helpful but i added the network layout with their ip addresses. Red color is `network X` , blue is `network Z`.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I tried using `port 3389` like this : `210.2.1.6:3389` but got the same error message as above.

Comment: Have you tried doing Remote Desktop using the IP address?

Comment: @Darius Yes. It doesn't work either, i used the port 5000 . something like this `210.2.1.65:5000`. It should work with full computer name anyway

Comment: Don't remote desktop (default port) works on Port 3389? And about full computer name, that has always been a strange case for me as it takes a while until a computer name is recognized on the LAN for me, so I tend to go with IP address. Eventually the computer name do get recognized, but usually not on my first attempt.

Comment: I will give it another try and update the result

Comment: Btw does workgroup matter when using remote desktop?

Comment: @ChrisAung No it doesn't.  It would help with this question to provide IP address for each network so we can see how the network is laid out.

Comment: try using telnet to see if there is a connection over the remote port. For example: telnet fullyQdomainName 3389 or telnet x.x.x.x 3389. That is ofcourse after you are able to ping them

Comment: You have X1, Z1 and Y1 all with the same address in the diagram above.  Can you clarify how that is working, or is it a typo?

Comment: @Paul it's typo..

Comment: Have you got routing for the 210.2.1.x network on the 193.3.1.x network and vice versa?

Comment: what do you mean by routing? can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the username you are using for remote login in PC X1 has a password. Otherwise try changing the password, even if that fails use a different username and password. In the laptop Y1 check if you have set network discovery and password protected sharing on in network properties. Having everything in the same workgroup helps if you are using names, otherwise use the IP addresses. Try these with default port, i.e. without specifying a port.

If the laptop's account is administrator and password is X and the XP computer's account used for remote connection is also named administrator but with a different password, say Y; then you might have errors. Either use same passwords or use different account names when in a workgroup environment. Make sure the computer names on PC and Laptop are also different and unique.

Comment: the PC X1 has password. In laptop Y1, both the network discovery  and password protected sharing is on.I also tried without specifying the port like this `210.2.1.6`. And the account names are not the same. Computer names are different.. still i can't get it working yet..

Comment: Then may be the RDP version is not compatible, check if you can get RDP 6.0 installed on vista and then try.